# ActiveRecord generates wrong relation HABTM name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using Rails to generate a HABTM relationship between my tables. My table name is `canvas`, but `canvas.singularize` will produce `canva`, which is not the correct word. So I've made some changes in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
inflect.irregular 'canvas', 'canvases'
```

This is my migration:

```
create_table :canvases do |t|
end

create_table :questions do |t|
end

create_join_table :canvases, :questions do |t|
  t.index  :question_id
  t.index  :canvas_id
end
```

However, running `CanvasQuestion.find_by_canvas_id_and_question_id(1,1)` in the console will generate this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "canvas_questions" 
does not exist LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"canvas_questions"'::regc...
```

It seems to me like ActiveRecord is trying to find the table `canvas_questions` instead of `canvases_questions`. Right now, I've to use Gem `composite_primary_keys` and change my model like this to make it work:

```
class CanvasQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'canvases_questions'
  self.primary_keys = :canvas_id, :question_id 
end
```

Is there a proper way to solve this? Because I'm thinking that right now I'm getting this error because CanvasQuestion is translated to `canvas_questions` instead of `canvases_questions` by ActiveRecord, even though I've changed my `canvas` word inflection to `canvases`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this `CanvasQuestion.find_by_canvas_id_and_question_id(1,1)` , you can't query with a **`HABTM join-table`** because the ***model*** for ***join-table*** shouldn't exist.

From the [***API doc***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)

> The join table should not have a primary key or a model associated
>   with it.

I tested your code in my project and when running `CanvasQuestion.find_by_canvas_id_and_question_id(1,1)` I got 
`NameError: uninitialized constant CanvasQuestion` So ***Rails*** is looking for a ***class*** **`CanvasQuestion`** which didn't exist.

My suggestion is to use **`has_many :through`**. Check this [***Choosing between `Habtm` and `has_many :through`***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) from the Guides. It will help you.

Comment: I was on holiday ;) The API doc reference is really helpful.. I did settled with has_many: :through in the end. Thanks!